Need formula to sum only positive numbers seen in a filtered range containing all types of integers
I am trying to create a google sheet formula to get "sum" of "only positive numbers" when I filter-out the range.
I am trying to merge subtotal function and Query function but not able to do it. May be there is some limitaiton to subtotal function. Need help in creating a formula by any other means
